# Cannot get a list of GitHub repositories via Auth0

Tags: reactjs, github, auth0

I am trying to list GitHub repositories in my app after the user has successfully authenticated with Auth0:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const Repositories = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently, user } = useAuth0();
  const [repositories, setRepositories] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
          audience: 'https://api.github.com/',
          scope: 'public_repo',
        });
        const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + user.nickname + '/repos', {
          headers: {
            Accept: `application/vnd.github+json`,
            Authorization: `token ${token}`,
          },
        });
        setRepositories(await response.json());
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

  if (!repositories) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {repositories.map((repository, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{repository.name}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Repositories;
```

But it does not work. I get an error in the console `Error: Service not found: https://api.github.com/`. What am I doing wrong? Are there any Auth0 examples that show how to authenticate against GitHub?

**UPD:**

Here is what my code is transformed into:

```
        const access_token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
          audience: 'https://dev-********.us.auth0.com',
          scope: ['read:users', 'read:user_idp_tokens'],
        }); 
        console.log("Access token: " + access_token)
        const userWithToken = await fetch("https://dev-********.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users/" + user.sub + "?include_fields=true", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
          }
        })
        const token = userWithToken.identities[0].access_token 
        console.log("Token:" + token)
        const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + user.nickname + '/repos', {
          headers: {
            Accept: `application/vnd.github+json`,
            Authorization: `token ${token}`,
          },
        });
        console.log(response)
```

But now the problem is that call to `https://dev-********.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users/` always fails. Either with 401 `Bad audience` error (if I specify https://api.github.com as an audience when doing `getAccessTokenSilently`) or `Consent is required` (if I specify `https://dev-********.us.auth0.com/api/v2/` as an audience) or plain 400 (if I call `getAccessTokenSilently` without audience or any params)

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as why an authentication with Auth0 would give you access to GitHub. Does GitHub support such an integration? Anyway, it looks as if `getAccessTokenSilently()` fails because you have no registered `https://api.github.com/` as an API on Auth0.

Comment: @Codo Yes, Auth0 will store third-party access tokens for use with APIs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Access Tokens that are issued when a user logs in with GitHub through Auth0.

**First**, GH issues an Access Token to Auth0. **Second**, Auth0 issues an Access Token to your application.

The first Access Token (the GH token) is stored in the Auth0 database with your user's info. It can be accessed via the Management API in the user's `identities` array; and is known as an *Identity Provider Access Token*.

This doc describes it in depth: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/identity-provider-access-tokens

Comment: added an update. please check and let me know if there is a potential solution

Comment: You need to use the Auth0 management API as the Audience. i.e. `https://dev-********.us.auth0.com/api/v2/`.

Consent required means that your user needs to consent, which can't be done silently. Can you add the audience to the initial request to authorize?

Comment: I have added audience to be `https://dev-********.us.auth0.com/api/v2/`, as suggested. But now it throws an error `Consent required` and I don't know how to provide the consent. I assume that there should be some kind of pop-up or redirect to a page where consent should be provided. It doesn't happen automatically in my case.